# Use of uninitialized value $a in concatenation (.) or string

Tags: regex, bash, shell, perl, perl-module

I am trying to remove the old files in a dir if the count is more than 3 over SSH

Kindly suggest how to resolve the issue.

Please refer the code snippet

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $HOME="/opt/app/latest";
my $LIBS="${HOME}/libs";
my $LIBS_BACKUP_DIR="${HOME}/libs_backups";
my $a;
my $b;
my $c;
my $d;

my $command =qq(sudo /bin/su - jenkins -c "ssh username\@server 'my $a=ls ${LIBS_BACKUP_DIR} | wc -l;my $b=`$a`;if ($b > 3); { print " Found More than 3 back up files , removing older files..";my $c=ls -tr ${LIBS_BACKUP_DIR} | head -1;my $d=`$c`;print "Old file name $d";}else { print "No of back up files are less then 3 .";} '");

print "$command\n";
system($command);
```

output:

```
sudo /bin/su - jenkins -c "ssh username@server 'my ; =ls /opt/app/latest/libs_backups | wc -l;my ; =``;if ( > 3); { print " Found More than 3 back up files , removing older files..";my ; =ls -tr /opt/app/latest/libs_backups | head -1;my ; =``;print "Old file name ";}else { print "No of back up files are less then 3 .";} '"
Found: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
Found: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute parts of your local perl script in an ssh session on a remote server? That will not work.

Comment: Look into Object::Remote. [Here is a good talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7hIyawUrCcQ) by the author from the German Perl Workshop 2014. It will essentially let you write Perl code locally, and execute it completely on a remote machine. It doesn't even matter what Perl version you have there.

Comment: You should also not use `$a` and `$b`. They are reserved global variables for `sort`.

Comment: Why are you sudoing when your command is running on an entirely different server?

Comment: I don't have access to the server so I am using sudo to run as jenkins user.

Comment: This is just not going to work the way you think it is. At the very least - figure out an ssh command that works _first_.

Comment: Never put `sudo` or `su` in a script. This is security breach. Instead run the script as `sudo` or `su`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new file and handling the dir check and deletion logic , scp file to remote server and executing in remote server , after completion removing the file.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename;
use File::Path;
use FindBin;
use File::Copy;

my $HOME="/opt/app/test/latest";
my $LIBS_BACKUP_DIR="${HOME}/libs_backups";

my $a="ls ${LIBS_BACKUP_DIR} | wc -l";
my $b=`$a`;
my $c="ls -tr ${LIBS_BACKUP_DIR} | head -1";
my $d=`$c`;
chomp($d);
print " count : $b\n";



if ($b > 3)
{
print " Found More than 3 back up files , removing older files..\n";
print "Old file name $d\n";
my $filepath="${LIBS_BACKUP_DIR}/$d";
rmtree $filepath;
}
else
 {
 print "No of back up files are less then 3 .\n";
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have three levels of escaping, you're bound to get it wrong if you do it manually. Use String::ShellQuote's `shell_quote` instead.

Furthermore, avoid generating code. You're bound to get it wrong! Pass the necessary information using arguments, the environment or some other channel of communication instead.

There were numerous errors in the interior Perl script on top of the fact that you tried to execute a Perl script without actually invoking `perl`!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

my $HOME = "/opt/app/latest";
my $LIBS = "$HOME/libs";
my $LIBS_BACKUP_DIR = "$HOME/libs_backups";

my $perl_script = <<'__EOI__';
   use strict;
   use warnings;

   use String::ShellQuote qw( shell_quote );

   my ($LIBS_BACKUP_DIR) = @ARGV;

   my $cmd = shell_quote("ls", "-tr", "--", $LIBS_BACKUP_DIR);
   chomp( my @files =  `$cmd` );
   if (@files > 3) {
      print "Found more than 3 back up files. Removing older files...\n";
      print "$_\n" for @files;
   } else {
      print "Found three or fewer backup files.\n";
   }
__EOI__

my $remote_cmd = shell_quote("perl", "-e", $perl_script, "--", $LIBS_BACKUP_DIR);
my $ssh_cmd = shell_quote("ssh", 'username@server', "--", $remote_cmd);
my $local_cmd = shell_quote("sudo", "su", "-c", $ssh_ccmd);
system($local_cmd);
```